# What is data registration state 13

Tags: android, registration

In Qcril response from < DATA_REGISTRATION_STATE 1indicates registered 2 indicate not registered. What is 13? Response will contain many parameters this is the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer, but perhaps useful for anyone else who stumbles here:

```
/**
 * RIL level registration state values from ril.h
 * ((const char **)response)[0] is registration state 0-6,
 *              0 - Not registered, MT is not currently searching
 *                  a new operator to register
 *              1 - Registered, home network
 *              2 - Not registered, but MT is currently searching
 *                  a new operator to register
 *              3 - Registration denied
 *              4 - Unknown
 *              5 - Registered, roaming
 *             10 - Same as 0, but indicates that emergency calls
 *                  are enabled.
 *             12 - Same as 2, but indicates that emergency calls
 *                  are enabled.
 *             13 - Same as 3, but indicates that emergency calls
 *                  are enabled.
 *             14 - Same as 4, but indicates that emergency calls
 *                  are enabled.
 * @hide
 */
```

More details [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/ServiceState.java), search for `RIL_REG_STATE_*`.